# Changing column headers to always have visible arrows

Tags: list, document-library, document

I have a document library and need to make the arrows that appear when you hover over a column to be always visible.  Is it possible to do this WITHOUT SharePoint designer?  The company I work for won't allow access to anyone and the person with access won't make edits such as that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following CSS should make the column arrows visible at all times, not only on hover:

```
a.ms-headerSortArrowLink > img {
    visibility: visible !important;
}
```

You can apply this CSS to:

- **a single list view** - you need access to edit list view pages. Steps: edit the list view page, add a Script Editor web part to the page, and then inside it paste the CSS above between the `<style>insert_CSS_here</style>` tags.
- **all list views in the site** - you need full control access on the site. Steps: create a CSS file with the above CSS, upload the file to the Site Assests library of the site, and then go to Site Settings > Master Page > Alternate CSS URL > pick third option > click Browse and select the CSS file uploaded earlier in the Site Assests library > click OK.
- **all lists views in the site collection** - you need to be a site collection admin. Same steps as the applying the CSS to all list views in a site, but you need to do those on the root site of the site collection.

Comment: Thank you!  I don't seem to have access to embed code either but I may be able to get someone with access to do it!